# Assign an image to a random div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm making a simple game and I was wondering how I could assign an image to a random div on page load. For example I have a two rows of div tags that are labeled as such -

```
<div id="1_1" class="mapsquare"></div>
<div id="2_1" class="mapsquare"></div>
<div id="3_1" class="mapsquare"></div>
<div id="1_2" class="mapsquare"></div>
<div id="2_2" class="mapsquare"></div>
<div id="3_2" class="mapsquare"></div>
```

I want to be able to add an image (Player sprite) to one of these divs randomly, when the page loads. This is all I have so far, but Im not sure how I could make this work with the div id's.

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x=document.getElementById("player")
x.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
}
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by assign image? add image tag in it or background image?

Comment: Yeah I want to be able to add an image tag to that div, the image would be of the player sprite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".mapsquare"),
    randomIndex = Math.floor( Math.random() * divs.length );
divs[randomIndex].appendChild(document.getElementById("player"));
```

Or, sorry, just saw the jQuery tag:

```
var $divs = $(".mapsquare");
$("#player").appendTo( $divs.get(Math.floor(Math.random() * $divs.length)) );
```

Basic demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DWfc6/

Of course given that many games involve quite a few random calculations you might like to put the random code into its own function, like this one [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks updating/trying it now here- http://xronn.co.uk/battlearena/battle.html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zCZkA/ You know why it doesnt work here? Spent a good hour trying different things

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('div.mapsquare:eq(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * $('div.mapsquare').length) + ')').append(player)
```

Comment: Similar to the first answer shall also try

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `#player` element is the image you want to append to a random div, try this:

```
var $player = $('#player');
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.mapsquare').length);
$('.mapsquare').eq(rnd).append($player);
```

Comment: The first div element would never be accessible with the `+ 1` at the end.

Comment: @kayen yep, just realised and fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use math.random to get the random div id value  like

```
var divName = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3) + "_" + Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
```

and then based on id you can add image

please refer the example **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OqEMoVU/1/edit)**
**http://jsbin.com/OqEMoVU/1/edit**

Comment: There is a, very small, chance that this code will error since it's possible for `Math.random()` to return `0`. You should really use `Math.floor()` in the future.